# Android: Update data by its Id

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been trying to update the data on sqlite database, but before the data will update the users will search for the Id of the data and will load to the Edittext. I have no error in my Logcat but when I click the update button it will only show the toast message and when I check the data, there is no changes. Please I need help..Please check my codes. Thank you..

My DatabaseHelper class:

```
  public void updateData(int id, String new_question, String new_ans1, String new_ans2, String new_ans3, String new_ans4, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase )
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_QUESTION, new_question);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER1, new_ans1);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER2, new_ans2);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER3, new_ans3);
        contentValues.put(AdminContact.Question.COLUMN_ANSWER4, new_ans4);


        sqLiteDatabase.update(AdminContact.Question.TABLE_QUIZ, contentValues, AdminContact.Question.ID +"="+id, null);
```

My Update class:

```
    EditText Search_Id, New_Question, New_Ans1, New_Ans2, New_Ans3, New_Ans4;
    DatabaseHelper helper;
    String SearchID, NewId, NewQuestion, NewAns1, NewAns2, NewAns3, NewAns4;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    TextView title_text;
    Button updateButton;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_contact);
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Search_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_search);
        New_Question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_question);
        New_Ans1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans1);
        New_Ans2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans2);
        New_Ans3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans3);
        New_Ans4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_ans4);
        title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        New_Question.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        title_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        updateButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button) ;

                sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

                question = New_Question.getText().toString();
                ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
                ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
                ans3 = New_Ans3. getText().toString();
                ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();

                helper.updateData(id,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void searchContact(View view) {

        SearchID = Search_Id.getText().toString();
        sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = helper.getData(SearchID, sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            NewQuestion = cursor.getString(0);
            NewAns1 = cursor.getString(1);
            NewAns2 = cursor.getString(2);
            NewAns3 = cursor.getString(3);
            NewAns4 = cursor.getString(4);
            NewId = SearchID;

            New_Question.setText(NewQuestion);
            New_Ans1.setText(NewAns1);
            New_Ans2.setText(NewAns2);
            New_Ans3.setText(NewAns3);
            New_Ans4.setText(NewAns4);
            New_Ans4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Ans3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Ans2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Ans1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            New_Question.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            title_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            updateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should try looking at the data in the database and confirm that its organized the way you think it is. In fact, you could install your app on an android emulator and then insert data and then use the command line tool sqlite3 in adb to interact with your database. and run the same query you think you're sending.

Comment: `if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button) ;` should end with a open-bracket instead of a semi-colon

Comment: Also, the value of `id` is never assigned, so it will always be `0`. Not sure if that is intentional?

Comment: you need to pass the SearchID to updateButton

Comment: like this helper.updateData(SearchID,id,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase)?????

Comment: Sir  cricket_007 and Sir John Joe can you post your comments as answer so that I can check them. Thank you

Comment: Sir John Joe I can now update the data on my sqlite because of your comments.. THANK YOU SIR

Comment: Glad you fix it..How you solve this? Put your answer at below, it may benefit to the others :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Button function to Update pass the SearchID.

 public void updateData(View view)
    {
        sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String question, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4;

        question = New_Question.getText().toString();
        ans1 = New_Ans1.getText().toString();
        ans2 = New_Ans2.getText().toString();
        ans3 = New_Ans3.getText().toString();
        ans4 = New_Ans4.getText().toString();

        helper.updateData(SearchID,question,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,sqLiteDatabase);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    }
```